# Вывод информации с input

Tags: php

Интересует вопрос, как можно реализовать вывод Имени и Фамилии с input'a с помощью $_POST и с обязательном использованием функции для данного действия.

```
if ($_POST) {
    function ($name, $surname)
         #code .....
}


<form method="post">
Name:  <input type="text" name="name_user" /><br />
Surname: <input type="text" name="surname_user" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" />
```

Вывод информации с инпута осуществляется на этой же странице без перезагрузки. Спасибо.

Comment: Если нужно выводить без перезагрузки, зачем нужен php?

Comment: без пeрезагрузки то же самое но с аякс запросом

Comment: @Hast насколько мне известно PHP не требует перезагрузки странцы при выполнении каких-либо функций

Comment: @OlegSevernuy PHP - это серверный язык программирования, а не клиентский как JS. То есть он начинает выполняться только в тот момент, когда его явно запросят. Это можно сделать либо загрузкой страницы, либо с помощью AJAX-запроса, как предложил misha11

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно -

```
<?php 
function Foo ($name,$surname) {
    echo $name.'<br />';
    echo $surname.'<br />';
    }
if(isset($POST)){
Foo($_POST['name_user'],$_POST['surname_user']);
}
?>
```

Comment: и не if ($_POST) а isset чтобы не выдало ошибку при отсуствии POST

Answer (score 0):

Доброе утро.
Можно начать со следующего:

```
<form method="post">
Name:  <input type="text" name="name_user" /><br />
Surname: <input type="text" name="surname_user" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" /> 
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">

 $('form').on('submit', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   var Data = $(this).serialize();

   $.ajax({
     url: 'file.php',
     type: 'POST',
     data: Data,
     success: function(data){
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
        var html = response.name + '<br>' + response.surname
        $('body').append(html)
     }
   })
})

</script>
```

Файл для обработки формы

```
<?php
  function test($name, $surname){
    $answer = ['name' => $name, 'surname' => $surname];
    echo json_encode($answer);
  }
  if(isset($_POST)){
    test($_POST['name_user'], $_POST['surname_user']);
  }
?>
```